# Is Redis a good option in this scenario?

Tags: sql, email, redis

The company sends emails (thousands) only during 2 hours (i.e. from 1am to 3am), some days even less, during the night, to thousands users. Later it stops, and does nothing else; the next day we use the same process but with new data in those emails.

The process we follow to send them is this:

1. Take content-data/personal-information for emails from SQL database
2. Build queues with these contents-data/personal-information in memory by using Redis
3. Send emails taking content-data/personal-information from memory Redis
4. Delete all content-data/personal-information in memory Redis.

The problem is that I'm not sure about if Redis is a good option in this case. It's working, but I think that for only two hours it's not necessary to use Redis. I'm new in the company, so I didn't build that, but I don't understand why they made it like this.

Comment: Can't you just work off the database? Why the queue?

Comment: That's my question!!, I'm new in the company, so I didn't build that, but I don't understand why they make this...

Comment: If it ain't broken, don't fix it. :)

Comment: jajajaja, yes I know, I know, but it's a question of curiosity, I'm begginer with Redis, but this case didn't make sense for me

Comment: Redis is a great queue, if this is your question. You only have to make sure that all data fits in memory.

Comment: Perhaps the queue is being used to keep track of which emails have been sent and which are pending, so that in case the job crashes it can pick up where it left? Otherwise with what you posted there's no apparent reason why this method would be "better" compared to just reading from the database directly, but you should probably research further why are they doing it this way before removing redis from the process IMHO.

Comment: thanks a lot, I'm sure is what you say. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Couple of notes:

1. If you're accessing the content and personal data once a day, you can easily get it from the relational database.
2. Redis is pretty awesome for caching. You can request data based on keys. We are using Redis in our development for speeding up "queries", accessing frequently used data, caching and to take the load of the Relational DB.
3. For accountability reasons, if you'd like to keep a log of the emails sent out, you'll gonna need to write back to the central DB, since you are clearing the Redis cache upon finish.

As far as I understand Redis is just another step in your whole process which seems to be unnecessary.